# I submitted the correct personal statement to the correct schools, but I realized I left highlights in my submission what should I do?

Tags: graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

I wrote my personal statements for two schools and they had the correct information for each school and submitted each statement to the correct school. But in my excitement to be completing my final two applications, I left highlighted sentences and words that I reviewed and finalized in my submitted essays. Being that I did this over the holiday, I labeled my drafts as "final" stepped away for a couple hours and just uploaded them to the portal and submitted my payments. I had a random epiphany scrolling through social media and realized my mistake. The Statement is completely edited and grammatically correct, but the highlighting is going to raise eyebrows. What is the best course of action in this instance? I do not believe that the portal used to upload my statements will cooperate to let me upload new versions of the statements since it is finalized. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> what should I do?

No action is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the portal web sites to see if they offer a chance to revise. If none is visible you might ask if you can find a contact email on the site. Otherwise I think you are out of luck. If the statement is good maybe the raised eyebrows won't matter in the final decision.

Answer (score 0):

What color are the highlights? There is a chance that everything you submit gets printed for review. If you highlight with say, dark red*, the black and white print might be illegible. Also it might leave an impression that you are at least sloppy or disorganized. With how trigger happy people are with elliminating applications, I think there is reason enough for at least sending an e-mail and asking what can be done.

*I actually printed one document with "red 3" highlight of apache open office. It printed like CIA's reducted documents.